# Как в inpute прописать данные из mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

В name надо вставить значение

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo '<input  type="checkbox" name=.$row[5]. value="a1" checked>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<input  type="checkbox" name='.$row[5].' value="a1" checked>';
}
```

И еще совет:
**mysql_fetch_array** - дает право использовать в $row[] название колонки. Иными словами, объединяет 
**mysql_fetch_assoc()** и **mysql_fetch_row()**

```
$row["название колонки таблицы"] = $row[номер колонки]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo '<input  type="checkbox" name='.$row[5].' value="a1" checked>';
}
```